Sony wh1000mx4 termal probe exceedes charging range
Im a complete begginer, english isn't my first language and im a new member to this forum so i would love if you were respectfull.
I've encounterned a problem repairing my sony wh-1000mx4 headphones. I bought them a couple weeks ago, knowing that the prevoius owner had them for a bit, they were i good conditon but the only thing was they couldn't charge it.
Diode responsible for signaling charging was blinking fast twice and then shutting down, which on the sony's troubleshooting webstie was listed as "Abnormal temperature". It seemed normal to me knowing that the guy selling me those headphones said on the motherboard had no connector for termistor which i thought would be an easy fix.
The headphones arrived without a connector nor a termistor and some missing elements but after inspecting the motherboard and finding high quality picktures of it on the internet i've searched up IC responsinble for charging battery and gone trought its specification. The IC in question is Texas instruments BQ27421 and from it's schmeatics i concluded that the termistor must have been 10kOhm.
The missing stuff where 3 out of the 4 pads from the also missing connector which i just figured the easiest way of fixing would be to solder 10k resistor on one of the left pads which i checked with the multimeter and it happens to be ground and other connected right to the capacitor down the road from traced lines. (one thing to note here 2 of these missing pads where just to hold down connector and had not tracers leading anywhere)


this webstie basicly links to other forum on which someone made high quality photos of that moterboard, it helps alot when trying to diagnose since the board is very, very little.
Even though, i've connected everything and checked multiple times with a multimeter the error still conctinous.
From the data sheet provided by the TI the bin(B1) pin should have 10kohm resistance to ground, and i would want to check it, i dont own a hot air gun and cant easily desolder that IC, the pin might (im totally not sure) be acessed from the other side of the board but when i measure its reasistance to ground, its 60kohm and it well exceedes the temperature, IC would allow the battery to work, on a 10ohm termistor
There is also a couple resistors missing which i know, where they connect, and it wouldn't be a problem for me to solder them back on but they have been sheered of by the person who had a look before me and i have no clue what reisistance i should put here. I couldn't find and info about the component right next to it

If anyone has an idea on what shall i try, or had seen a board named A-5020-595-A anywhere aviable on the internet for a reasonble price (around 25 euro) as guy in this post had bought one, i would be more than happy to recive a link. I couldn't have asked the guy since it's a new account and i can't post comments yet. Would be happy for any feedback. Love you guys, and late Merry Cristmas

You can post comments on your own post but not to anyone's answers... Anyways. I suspect the "abnormal temperature" blinking code you've identified as likely a voltage regulator that has its own current sensing. If it has missing resistors, the current reading will see the open circuit as infinite resistance, thinking that the circuit is really hot and thus possibly sending an over temperature alert to that Atmel microcontroller that will shut everything down.
